# Problem of finding shortest proof - how complex is it?

Tags: logic, computational-complexity, computational-mathematics, kolmogorov-complexity

For first order theories, is it correct that there is a brute force algorithm that tells us the shortest proof length for any given theorem ('length' means the sum of the lengths of the formulas that appear as lines in the proof)?

Are there algorithms better than brute force? What is the complexity class for the problem?

Comment: If your theories are allowed to have infinitely many axioms (defined by some recursive enumeration of the axioms), then there is no such brute force algorithm: the shortest possible proof of $\vdash \phi$ is when $\phi$ is an axiom, but it would require an infinite search through the axioms to find out whether that is so. If you restrict to finitely axiomatisable theories, then there is a brute force algorithm that just enumerates all the proofs of length $1$, then $2$ and so on and will find the shortest proof if the input $\phi$ is a theorem. I imagine the complexity will be enormous.

Comment: @RobArthan Note that that depends on how we interpret "length." If we mean *number of symbols* instead of *number of steps*, then an infinite theory is not a problem - we just need a finite language and a c.e. theory.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I don't understand your comment: any proof of $\phi$ must contain all the symbols in $\phi$, so if $\phi$ is an axiom, then the shortest proof of $\vdash \phi$ must be the one that just cites that axiom.

Comment: @RobArthan Sorry, I should have written "computable" instead of "c.e." - as long as axiomhood is checkable, we're fine.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: no worries! Any theory with an r.e. set of axioms also has a recursive set of axioms, but just given a recursive enumeration of the axioms, you can't design an algorithm that is guaranteed to find a shortest proof.

Comment: @RobArthan More to the point, different axiomatizations of the same theory will have different proof lengths. So it's really all about the particular choice of axiomatization.

Comment: @RobArthan Is this generalizable to all first order theorems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two reasonable ways to measure the length of a proof: by **steps** or by **symbols**. For step-length, we can brute-force-search for proofs and be certain we've found the shortest one *as long as our axiom system is finite* - for symbol-length, we only need that the *language* is finite and our axiom system is *computably axiomatized* (e.g. $\mathsf{PA}$ and $\mathsf{ZFC}$).

That said, in either case we have a serious issue as far as complexity is concerned: as long as our axiom system is "sufficiently rich," for every computable function $F$ there is some theorem $\varphi$ which has no proof of length $\le F(length(\varphi))$. (Basically, we're looking at the Busy Beaver function in disguise when we talk about bounding proof searches ahead of time.)

That said, this doesn't rule out $(i)$ efficient proof search in simpler theories or $(ii)$ efficient proof search for particularly simple results. There's a rich literature on this topic, beginning with the already-interesting case of **propositional** proof search - "automated theorem proving" is a good keyword for this.

Comment: As per my comments on the question, you are quite right, but there is a delicate point here: the usual presentations of systems like PA and ZFC give a recursive enumeration of the axioms and not an effective test for axiomhood. It so happens that the effective tests for axiomhood in these systems are easy to give. If you take the axioms of PA to be the theorems of PA, you have an r.e. axiomatisation but no algorithm for finding the shortest proof of a given theorem.

Comment: Another subtlety in the case of step-length is the properties of the underlying proof system. Even if there's a finite number of non-logical _axioms_ in the theory, filling in intermediate inference steps in the proof will often require us to guess things like cut formulas or existential witnesses. For "reasonable" proof systems this shouldn't be an insurmountable problem, though -- a proof search can be smarter than blindly iterating through all the  possible cut formulas (etc) one by one.

Comment: @RobArthan I disagree with "the usual presentations of systems like PA and ZFC give a recursive enumeration of the axioms and not an effective test for axiomhood." The usual presentations very obviously *do* give an effective test for axiomhood.

Comment: I said that the effective tests for membership of the axiom schemata for PA and ZFC were easy to give. However, under all the presentations I am familiar with, the axiom schemata are presented as, what I view as, functions that map parameter formulas to formulas, not algorithms for detecting when a formula is an axiom. I have never come across an elementary text on first-order logic that discusses pattern-matching algorithms prior to giving the axiom schemata of these systems.

Comment: @RobArthan:  Don't the standard proofs of Gödel's incompleteness have a function axiom(n) that returns true if $n$ is the Gödel number of an axiom and false otherwise?

Comment: @RossMillikan: yes: a system with an r.e. set of axioms has a recursive set of axioms (if the r.e. set of axioms is $\phi_1, \phi_2, \ldots$ then $\phi_1, \phi_1\land \phi_2, \ldots$ is an equivalent recursive set of axioms). But that doesn't help with finding the shortest set of proofs given a particular r.e. set of axioms.

Comment: @RobArthan The map sending a formula to its corresponding separation or replacement instance is obviously computable, and the presentation of the ZFC axioms says "$\varphi$ is an axiom iff it is one of this finite set or there is some $\psi$ of length $<\vert\varphi\vert$ such that $\varphi$ is either the separation or replacement instance corresponding to $\psi$." This is clearly a computable description; the only subtlety is the explicitly bounded existential quantifier, but I consider that implicit. I guess I take a slightly looser stance than you here.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: yes, you've given a very succinct proof that the axiom schemata for ZF gives a decidable set of axioms. But my stance is that we could give an alternative r.e. set of axioms that are not decidable and would thwart any algorithm that tried to find minimal length proofs.

Comment: @RobArthan Of course that's true, but I don't see what that has to do with the *standard presentation*, which is what we were talking about.

Comment: @NoahSchweber , When you say that "computably axiomized", does this mean that the symbolic proof is subject to Kolmogorov complexity also, or is this something that first have to be satisfied by the syntax or steps for recursive primitives to end in a Q.E.D. result and then reevaluate next in terms of stepwise procedure? What I mean is that can both be computed at once or is there some kind of issue when computing one without respect to the other?

Comment: @ShawnW I have no idea what that means. "Computably axiomatized" just refers to the set of axioms being computable; I don't know what "is subject to Kolmogorov complexity" means (and in fact Kolmogorov complexity is irrelevant to this particular question), or what "recursive primitives" are.

Comment: @NoahSchweber What are your comments on the complexity class question? Thank you.

Comment: @ShawnW I honestly have no idea what that means.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124331/discussion-between-shawn-w-and-noah-schweber).

Comment: @ShawnW "What are your comments on the complexity class question?" See the second paragraph of my answer.